# Tableau moving average

Tags: tableau-api, moving-average, cumulative-sum

I have to count distinct users who log everyday to define whether they are active or not. One user is considered "active" if they logged in at least once in last 14 days.

Given a day X, my metric is calculating the % of distinct active users on the total registered.

So: % Active on day X = (#distinct users having logged at least once during the period X to X-13) / (total registered users on day X).

I can manually calculate it for day X.

What I find challenging is creating a time series of this metric (everyday one %, everyday a rolling period of 14 days).

So:

% Active on day X = (#distinct users having logged at least once during the period X to X-13) / (total registered users on day X),

% Active on day X-1 = (#distinct users having logged at least once during the period X-1 to X-14) / (total registered users on day X-1),

% Active on day X-2 = (#distinct users having logged at least once during the period X-2 to X-15) / (total registered users on day X-2),

etc.

useful information: I have a column containing the UserID, one containing every day he logged id (in case of multiple daily logs, still one row per day) and one column for the registration date.

Comment: Hi Joe, thanks for the detailed pseudo-code.  Have you taken a look at tableau table calculations yet?  Have you tried any calculations in tableau thus far?

Comment: In particular I would try taking a look at a function like WINDOW_SUM(COUNTD([User_ID]),-13,0) and filtering for only login records.